Showing that $SL(2, \mathbb R)$ is non amenable.
Here is the question I am thinking about part $(3)$ in it:
Consider the action of $GL(2, \mathbb R)$ on the unit circle $S^1 \subset \mathbb R^2$ where the matrix $A$ acts by $$A: v \to \frac{Av}{|Av|}$$ Let $$A =\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 
\end{pmatrix}, B = r_{\pi/4} =\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2}/2 \\
-\sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2}/2
\end{pmatrix}$$
Note that $B$ is the matrix that gives a $90$ degree rotation. We can assume without proof that $A$ and $B$ generate a free group.
Here is what I want to show:
(1) Show that the action of the group generated by $\langle A,B\rangle$ has no invariant measures on $S^1.$
(2) Conclude that the free group on 2 generators is non-amenable.
(3) Conclude that $GL(2, \mathbb R)$ is non- amenable, and adapt this argument to show that $SL(2, \mathbb R)$ is non-amenable.
My Questions are:
1-Could anyone clarify to me how can I conclude $(3)$ from $(1) \& (2)$ please?
2-Also, I did not get the full picture of proving that $GL(2,\mathbb R$ is non amenable and how it will differ from th proof that $SL(2,\mathbb R$ is non-amenable.
Could someone clarify these points to me please?
Here is my definition of amenability:
A semigroup $G$ is amenable if any time $G$ acts on a compact metric space $X,$ there is an invariant measure $\mu$ i.e. $\forall g \in G, g_* \mu = \mu.$ Where a semigroup is an associative monoid.

Here is a similar way of proving it for $SL_2(\Bbb R)$. Using the theory of fractional linear transformations, we can find elements $h_1,h_2 ∈ PSL(2,\Bbb R)$ generating a subgroup which is isomorphic to the free group $F_2$. Since $F_2$ is not amenable, $PSL(2,\Bbb R)$ and hence $SL(2,\Bbb R)$ is not amenable. Here we use that every closed subgroup of an amenable group is amenable, and every quotient is amenable. For more details and proofs on amenable groups see these notes by Alain Valette.
